# How to fix math functions

Tags: c#, .net

http://ideone.com/XjMJBa

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Cos(1e27));
    }
}
```

Starting from some value `Math.Cos` and `Math.Sin` are starting to return their argument instead of value inside of [-1, +1] segment. For example above the output is

```
1E+27
```

Why it is so and is it possible to fix such behaviour?

Comment: Exactly as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos(v=vs.110).aspx): "Acceptable values of *d* range from approximately -9223372036854775295 to approximately 9223372036854775295. For values outside this range, the Cos method returns *d* unchanged rather than throwing an exception."

Comment: You cannot "fix" the original methods as they have been documented to function like this. You can, however, create your own Cos and Sin methods that work more like what you'd expect.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - you'd also have to introduce a different data type than `double` here - I suspect why they don't support higher values is you're already at a point where the lack of precision means that the different between successive representable values is larger than π

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, but [such code in C++](http://codepad.org/8QbS9HPC) calculates the value. Why such difference was introduced?

Comment: @Qwertiy - it calculates *a* value, but how precise is the calculation? An IEEE 754 double contains 53 bits of precision. When you're up at numbers like 9223372036854775295, you'd need 63 bits or precision to represent that exactly. So it's already at the point where that "value" could represent any number of complete revolutions. I'd personally have picked a lower value to cut off at.

Comment: `double SinFixed(double d) { d = Math.Sin(d); return Math.Abs(d) <= 1 ? d : 0; }`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, for every value of `double` type exists some rational namber which is exactly equal to the original value. I expect that it calculates the cos of such value.

Comment: @Qwertiy - hopefully you've already got the picture, given you've accepted an answer. But up at the ranges we're talking about, there are thousands of *integers* that all map to the same double value. It's highly doubtful that any input will exactly map to a specific, representable, double. And so it's a crap shoot - at these levels, the original input may have led to any output in the range from -1 to 1.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes, but if math coprocessor can calculate _some_ value, then why should we prefer some _other_ value instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Trigonometric* functions (`Sin`, `Cos` and alike) a periodic with a period of *2 pi* (`2 * Math.PI`). However, since `Math.PI` is `double` and thus has *16-17 correct digits only* you can't compute `1e27` by naive (we require at least **27 digits**):

```
  Double result = Math.Cos(1e27); // totally wrong.
```

To perform the task, you need first appropriate `pi` value, e.g. from here

http://www.piday.org/million/

And we have to work with `BigInteger` as well:

```
  int exponent = 27;
  const String piString = "314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054"; 

  BigInteger pi2 = BigInteger.Parse(piString) * 2;
  int scale = piString.Length - 1; // 2 * pi is not that big integer, it's 6.28...
  BigInteger argument = BigInteger.Pow(10, exponent + scale);

  // Now let's compute the double value (fraction) that's reminder of 1e27 % (2 * PI)
  String remainder = (argument % pi2)
    .ToString()
    .PadLeft(piString.Length, '0')
    .Insert(1, "."); // we can have x.xxx, 0.xxx, 0.0xxx etc. remainders 

  Double fraction = 
    Double.Parse("0." + remainder.Substring(0, 20), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  // and now, finally
  Double result = Math.Cos(fraction);
```

Finally, the actual result is

> -0.695977596990354

Note, that *naive* C++ computation (taken from *Qwertiy* comment which is `0.849247`) is totally wrong, since even C++ `double` doesn't support `pi` 27 digits.

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%281000000000000000000000000000%29&a=TrigRD_R) doen't agree with both walues. And you are ignoring difference between 1e27 and its representation in double. Anyway, thank you for this idea.

Comment: Sorry, but *Wolfram* unlike `Math.Cos(1e27)` computes Cos(1e27 *degrees*) not *radians*. That´s why you have that difference.

Comment: No, I've changed the unit - there is a link bellow input line.

Comment: @Qwertiy: I have to apologize, my initial implementtation was incorrect. The error was in the `String remainder = ...` I didn't find out that remainder could well be in `x.xxxx...` format, not necessary in `0.xxxx`. So Wolfram is right

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The angle, a, must be in radians. Multiply by Math.PI/180 to convert degrees to radians.
>
> Acceptable values of a range from approximately -9223372036854775295
>   to approximately 9223372036854775295. For values outside of this
>   range, the Sin method returns a unchanged rather than throwing an
>   exception.

Comment: Why was it made in such way? For example, C++ calculates the value: http://codepad.org/8QbS9HPC

Answer (score 0):

"The angle, d, must be in radians. Multiply by Math.PI/180 to convert degrees to radians.
Acceptable values of d range from approximately -9223372036854775295 to approximately 9223372036854775295. For values outside this range, the Cos method returns d unchanged rather than throwing an exception."

ref -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the math for Sin, Cos computation and the available number of bits to represent information stored, the real value.

To compute the Cos function, for example as you asked here, you need to compute this:

```
Cos(x) = 1 - x*x/2! + x*x*x*x/4! - x*x*x*x*x*x/6! + ...
```

If your number is at left(negative) or right(positive) limit borders of the data type used for storage of number, then you get fast into problems, because if you are near such limit, then computing x^2, x^4, x^6 is breaking outside of the data type limit pretty fast...

Sure, there are ways to chose some less violent algorithms to compute Sin/Cos, but there are limits to that.

The second thing here is, that for a longer time, math computations are thanks to behaviour like this easy and prone to errors. If the method does not mind to compute the result, it should end with an exception to provide information, where it failed. I saw many algorithms, (some were mine :) ), where such details were overlooked, producing magical results, and it ends up with NaN's or like here, returning back same value. It gets pretty hard to hunt these math errors with numbers, limits, etc in complex algorithms...